# Mysql: backup on insert?

Tags: mysql, backup

Is there any out-of-the-box solution to backup a mysql database with e.g. mysqldump etc. if a special event in the database takes place?
There is a regular scheduled backup every day, but everytime a insert in a defined table is executed, I want to dump the whole database. What is the best (easiest ?) solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html).